# Error al reiniciar el servicio de FreeRADIUS

Tags: debian, switch

Muy buenas tengan todos.

Estoy tratando de configurar Radius en Debian 12 para controlar el acceso a unos switches extreme networks. Soy nuevo en el sistema operativo y en Radius.
Primero cree la base de datos de la siguiente manera.

```
**CREATE DATABASE radius;
GRANT ALL ON radius.* TO 'radius'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT;**
```

Despues modifique el siguiente archivo "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/sql" para agregar los siguientes parámetros:

```
  **driver = "rlm_sql_mariadb"
                database = "mysql"
                server = "localhost"
                port = 3306
                login = "radius"
                password = "password"
                radius_db = "radius"**
```

Pase a modificar el archivo "/etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf" para agregar los switch

```
**client switch1 {
    ipaddr = 192.168.1.10  
    secret = mysecret       
    require_message_authenticator = no
    nas_type = other
    shortname = switch1    
}**
```

Y por ultimo modifique el archivo "/etc/freeradius/3.0/users" para poder agregar los usuarios

```
**alan {
    Cleartext-Password := "password123"
    Reply-Message = "Welcome, alan!"
}**
```

Al momento de querer reiniciar el servicio de radius me aparece el siguiente error

[error al reiniciar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJKXD.png)

[sudo freeradius -cx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjMnD.png)

[systemctl status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqiFX.png)

[journalctl -xeu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dbV5.png)

Espero quede claro cual es el problema, ojala me puedan ayudar con esto y disculpen mis bajos conocimientos en este tema. Cualquier pregunta la pueden hacer.

Saludos

Comment: Qué hay en el archivo radiusd.conf? Tuvo modificaciones?

Comment: Hola AlanConker, bienvenido, la preguntas/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos, 
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.